# Using DOM parser in Android

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I'm using the DOM parser to retrive information from a XML file that looks like this:

```
<data>
    <metData>
        <wantedInformation>
    </metData>
    <metData>
        <Information>
    </metData>
    <metData>
        <Information>
    </metData>
<data>
```

The problem is because I don't know how to parse only the first part of `<metData>`. I don't need the second and the third part, but the parser displays them anyway.

The xml file is from a weather forcast site:
http://www.meteo.si/uploads/probase/www/fproduct/text/sl/fcast_SLOVENIA_MIDDLE_latest.xml
and I need just the following line: `<nn_shortText>oblačno</nn_shortText>`

Comment: Your file content did not come through - you need to quote that as code.

Comment: Tomazin: Which tag data you want to parse

Comment: That kind of XML document would throw an exception as it is not well formed.

Comment: I've edited my question and added link to a XML file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pls take care whether your XML file is well formed or not,

You have to the notice three methods which i had shown below, they are

```
    1. getElementsByTagName - Mention the tag which you want to parse
    2.getChildNodes - retervies the child node 
    3.getNodeValue()- with the help of this method you can access the
 value of particular tag
```

Step 1: Create a Method to parse _Information_Value ,inorder to parse the data of Information tag

```
String[] infoId=null;

public  void  parse_Information_Value() throws UnknownHostException{


        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        try {

            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dom = builder.parse(this.getInputStream());
            org.w3c.dom.Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName("metData");
            int a=items.getLength();
            int k=0;

            for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
                Message_category message = new Message_category();
                Node item = items.item(i);
                NodeList properties = item.getChildNodes();
                for (int j = 0; j < properties.getLength(); j++) {
                    Node property = properties.item(j);
                    String name = property.getNodeName();
                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("wantedInformation")) {
                        message.setId(property.getFirstChild()
                                .getNodeValue());
                        infoId[k]=property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                        k++;
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {         }

    }
```

Comment: For More Information, Refer my Blog http://sankarganesh-info-exchange.blogspot.com/2011/04/parsing-data-from-internet-and-creating.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your document, you may also want to use at a streaming oriented parser like [SAX](http://www.megginson.com/downloads/SAX/) or [Stax](http://stax.codehaus.org/Home), which does not pull the whole document into memory and thus needs less memory than DOM.

Good thing is that SAX is already built into Android, so you can use it right away.
See [this link](https://github.com/pilhuhn/TurtleCar/blob/master/src/de/bsd/turtlecar/Board.java#L30) for a usage example.

Comment: I know this, but sax parser has more classes. With DOM I can just include it in one class (Activity) to check one wanted parameter and than use toast to display it.