# How to create, read & write XML file in Android by using DocumentBuilderFactory Android application

Tags: android, xml

I am implementing one service this service using my application. In the Android app how to create XML file and how to read and write in XML file (in our resource folder, not using SD card).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using DOM parser in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140603/using-dom-parser-in-android)