# Android, storage custom ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, storage

I've read many topic on stackoverflow,and google, about this argument but i can't orient myself with writing custom ArrayList into files ! 
I've an ArrayList of type "CustomType". "CustomType" have two String variable : "name" and "description".

I want to save this ArrayList for reading it after closing and reopening my app. 
Does anyone help me doing this? and does anyone explain me what happen when i save/read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could write it simply as a csv file, like this,

```
1,name,desc
2,name2,desc2
3,name3,desc3
...
```

or you could use `gson` library - http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/, to convert it into a `json` string and then write it to a file, that way when you read it you could directly get the object from `json`,

i would personally use the second method,

Edit: for writing to csv

```
try
{
  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("<path>/MyFile.csv");
  while(lst.next())
  {
     for(int i = 0; i < columnSize; i++)
     {
        writer.append(i);
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append(lst.get(i).getName());
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append(lst.get(i).getDesc());
     }
     writer.append('\n');
  }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

(assuming the object in side the ArrayList has methods `getName()` and `getDesc()` )

this might be helpful in reading it again,

[Get and Parse CSV file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360628/get-and-parse-csv-file-in-android)

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the answer ! is a simple way to use cvs file?

Comment: Also csv file is a simple text file with .csv extension (csv - comma seperated values)

Comment: Thank you for the code !! i prefer this way, it seems easy ^^

Answer (score 1):

To save any kind of data you have to choose any of the available data storage tequinue

```
1)shared preferences
2)internal storage
3)external storage 
4)Sqlite
5)internet server
```

detailed docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

throgh any one of these way you can store ArrayList or other data which you are using to populate the screen , so every time user will open the app data will be loaded from stored location

Comment: yes ! i've read this docs but i don't understand what i've to do in my specific situation, i think i have to use internal storage ( my data will be not bigger than 400/500Kbyte..

Answer (score 0):

You could use XML files too:

- http://androidideasblog.blogspot.com/2010/01/read-write-and-parse-xml-file-in.html
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/
- [how to create ,read & write xml file in android by using DocumentBuilderFactory android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327164/how-to-create-read-write-xml-file-in-android-by-using-documentbuilderfactory)
- http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=30363

This way you can use all kind of text and symbols, if you are using a CSV you can not use the 'separator' in your content.